# How to open a py/pyw file with IDLE by a code in python?

Tags: python

For example, I want to open a file D:\happy\0.pyw
here I want to edit the file with IDLE, not just click open it.
When I open a .py/.pyw document, I click the right part of the mouse and choose **Edit with IDLE**, it works. I want to find how to do this as a code in python.
Assume I have known the position of idle.py is C:\python\idle.py
My code is below. How to change the code?

```
import os

def open_app(dir):
    os.startfile(dir)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    b=r'D:\happy\0.pyw'
    open_app(b)
```

Comment: I think that what you are looking for is `os.system`

Comment: @Tony it doesn't work

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "***", line 27, in <module>
    os.system('D:\python\idle.py','D:\happy\0.pyw')
TypeError: system() takes at most 1 argument (2 given)

Comment: IDLE, as shown, is a python script so you should call python on it. And you do need combine the arguments as shown in the documentation

Comment: hello Tony, is there a clear code example to use IDLE open file?